# ES6 и его поведение. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы, ecmascript-6

Всем привет. Хотел бы узнать мнение опытных кодеров, почему такое поведение у метода filter. 
Вообщем изучая Ajax мне стало интересно, а можно ли получить массив с сервера не преобразовывая его методом `$dataSer = json_encode($_SERVER);` и получая на клиенте `let data = JSON.parse(data);` , а тупо закинуть на сервере `print_r($_SERVER);` и попытаться воссоздать на клиенте результат который бы я получил парсом.

На клиенте 
т.к. в чистом виде

```
    Array
    (
        [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
        [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
        [HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://127.1.0.0:5500

и т.д.
```

Я начинающий и скажем план готовил на ходу примерно должно было так.
Мне нужно для начала получить чистые массивы построчно, а потом я предполагал их делить убрав при этом =>. Ну далее что нибудь

```
    let regV = /\[\w+]\s=>\s.+/g;//выбирает строку от [  и до конца строки
    let arr = data.match(regV);
    console.dir(arr);
//результат
0: "[HTTP_HOST] => localhost"
1: "[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive"
2: "[HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://127.1.0.0:5500"
```

Вот дальше меня удивило.

```
let spl = arr[0].split('=>');//нормально 
//результат
0: (2) ["[HTTP_HOST] ", " localhost"]
```

Ну думаю создам фильтр

```
let arrFilter = arr.filter((item)=>{
  console.dir(item.split('=>'));//тут норм, на выходе не норм
  return item.split('=>');

});
console.dir(arrFilter);
//никакого результата
0: "[HTTP_HOST] => localhost"
1: "[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive"
2: "[HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://127.1.0.0:5500"
```

Что не так?
метод map справился с этой задачей. 
/------------------------------------------------------------------/

Вот немного велосипеда.
Ассоциативный массив на php можно передать прямо так

```
print_r($_SERVER);
//var_export($_SERVER): или так.

И получить на JS. Работает как на обычном объекте так и на Map.

function requesServer(data){

  let regExpForMatch = /'.+|\[.+/gmi;
  let regExpForSplit = /['\[]|^\)|['\]]| => |\,$/gmi; 

  let arrMatch = data.match(regExpForMatch);//выборка нужного текста построчно в массив
  let dataServer = {};//данные перенёс в объект

  let arrMap = arrMatch.map((item)=>{

    let arrSplit = item.split(regExpForSplit);

    if(arrSplit[3] === ""){
      for(let i = 2; i <= arrSplit.length; i++){
        if(i==arrSplit.length-1){dataServer[arrSplit[1]] = ''; break;}
        if(arrSplit[i]==''){continue;}
        dataServer[arrSplit[1]] = arrSplit[i]; break; }  
    }else{
      dataServer[arrSplit[1]] = arrSplit[3]
    }

return [arrSplit[1], (arrSplit[3] == "")?arrSplit[4]:arrSplit[3]];                     
});

let dataServer1 = new Map(arrMap);//можно закинуть 

console.dir(dataServer);
console.dir(dataServer1);
}
```

Comment: в начале вопроса _почему такое поведение у метода filter_, в конце пример с map, как это все связано между собой?

Comment: Не спал почти сутки. Опечатался, но всё же я пришёл к методу map

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно не понимаю что за велосипед вы изобретаете, но вот на выходе всё вполне ожидаемо:[image: Сплит и Фильтрация]

То есть вот вы разбили строку на массив строк "[Ключ] => значение", после чего фильтр преобразует массив вот так:

```
// Было
[
  "[Ключ0] => значение0",
  "[Ключ1] => значение1",
  ...
]

// Стало
[
  ["[Ключ0] ", " значение0"],
  ["[Ключ1] ", " значение1"],
  ...
]
```

Если Вам нужно превратить это всё в обьект, то придётся продежаться по всем парам вот так:

```
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arrFilter.length; i++) {
  let keyValue = arrFilter[i]
  obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1]
}
```

Но лучше конечно использовать JSON, потому что искать нужную пару по массиву пар, где ключи ещё нужно проверять на равенство искомому ключу... Ну это жесть вообщем.

Comment: Ну насчёт искать пару я об этом думал, за это let arr = data.match(regV); отвечает. она тупо создаёт массив строкой же. Теперь ключ значение в одном массиве.

Comment: А что собственно у Вас не работает? Какой неожиданный результат был получен? Просто просматриваю вопрос и не очень понимаю что ожидалось...

Comment: Велосипед я изобретаю для того чтоб на практике понять как методы работают. Вот теперь сижу гадаю как добиться полноценного объекта. let arrFilter = arrMap.map((v,i,a)=>{
    let ob = Object.assign({}, v);
    return ob;
});

console.dir(arrFilter); положительного результата не дало. Присутствуют индексы Вообщем результат {0: "[HTTP_HOST] ", 1: " localhost"}  , а я по пытаюсь добиться {[HTTP_HOST] : "localhost"}

Comment: Аа, так тебе обьект нужен? Ну смотри, сейчас отредактирую свой ответ

Comment: И вот если вместо map обратиться к методу filter то результата от метода split не будет. Собственно меня это ещё смутило. Будто filter не взаимодействует с другими методами внутри

Comment: Но filter - это не map! Map создаёт массив из преобразованных элементов исходного. Filter создаёт новый массив из тех и только тех элементов, что прошли фильтрацию. 
Колбэк для map должен возвращать преобразованный элемент.
Колбэк для filter - true или false, то есть оставить или отбросить.
Подробнее почитай тут https://learn.javascript.ru/